# Pyside does something weird with locale

Tags: unicode, pyside

here are the relevant code lines for a unicode/pyside related problem :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8
...
msgBox = QtGui.QMessageBox()
msgBox.setText('é')
print 'é'
....
```

The print does what it should, implying my locale is utf-8, and printenv confirms it. On the other hand, the msgBox shows 'Ã©', unless I prefix the string with 'u'. Is that normal, and do I really have to prefix every string with u in order to use Pyside, when python never raises a problem?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 2.X there are two data types for strings: byte code and unicode. With u you choose unicode with nothing you choose byte code. If you `print bytes('é')` you see where PySide/PyQt get their data from. So it probably is normal.

The easy way out is using Python 3.X which just has unicode and won't bother you with the difference.

Not sure who is actually doing something that shouldn't be done, the `print` function Python 2.X or PySide/PyQt for Python 2.X, so I make it community wiki.

Comment: Integrating engine and gui, we realized the engine was coded in Python3. So we decided to put it all in Python3, and this problem has disappeared. Thank you.